# solve $(x^2y^3+2xy)dy=dx$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$(x^2y^3+2xy)dy=dx$$

My attempt:-
$\frac{dx}{dy}=(xy)^2y+2xy$

let $xy=u$
so the DE becomes
$$\frac{1}{y} \frac{du}{dy}-1 = u^2y+2u$$

how do I solve this?

Comment: **Hint:** The ODE $\frac{dx}{dy}=y^3x^2+2yx$ is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rearranging a bit, the equation looks like
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} - 2yx = y^3x^2,
$$
which is a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliDifferentialEquation.html)
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} + p(y)\,x = q(y)\,x^n
$$
with exponent $n=2$.

Thus, the substitution we want is (*try it yourself before revealing*):

> $$ u = x^{1-2} = x^{-1} $$ so $$\begin{align} x &= u^{-1} \\ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} &= -u^{-2} \, \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y}\end{align}$$

This results in the first-order *linear* equation:

> $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y} + 2y \, u = -y^3 $$

which can be solved by the method of [integrating factor](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations).